# Will "azure api app" restart itself per some default policy?

Tags: web-services, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-apps

I created one azure api app by C# in visual studio.

After publish form visual studio I found occasionally it will "restart"(not sure whether it is a restart coz I found no exceptions in application insights) itself.

Per check on application insights each time the "restart" observed there was a long response time for REST request(maybe more than 1 second, mostly the same REST handle only takes less than 100 ms).

So it means for published "azure api app" there will be some default policies from Azure? Say when it detects abnormal REST response(say handle time is too long than normal) it will restart itself?

I add the trace in WebApiApplication constructor so that I can confirm the restart via checking on the trace:

```
    public WebApiApplication() : 
    {
        Log.Info("api log check0309");
    }
```

The Rest handler is as the below: no other operation but to return 200

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{customerId}/capabilities")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Capability))]
public virtual IHttpActionResult GetCapabilities([LogContext] string customerId)
{
    Log.Info("Get capabilities");
    return Ok
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it means for published "azure api app" there will be some default policies from Azure?

I'm not sure what about the restart on your side. But the first time you visit web page, there really need a long time to response. Because you need to load your project in cache.  If you refresh the same page many time, you could see the first time of request is too long.

Comment: Thanks for comments. If I did not trigger REST request to the app, there will no restart. Only when I trigger REST request to the app the restart is observed occasionally.

Comment: Could you provide related code or screenshot about your settings?

Comment: Thanks for support.  I think you are the Azure support in MS?To accelerate the progress I would like to reach out to MS for support on call and mail, which may be more efficient.
How can I get the support from MS? I made call to Azure China yet they mentioned that mine is not China edition so they can not support.
Where can I get the support from MS? Any suggestions?

Comment: In fact the code is simple for the handler on REST I return 200 without any more operations.


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{customerId}/capabilities")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(Capability))]
        public virtual IHttpActionResult GetCapabilities([LogContext] string customerId)
        {
            Log.Info("Get capabilities");

            return Ok(new Capability { Capabilities = new string[0]});
        }
    }

Comment: The issue is: sometimes the handle on REST only takes 50 ms, yet will be 600 ms for the same REST next time and then web app restart(i found this by checking the trace in WebApiApplication constructor). Why does the time cost varies so much for the same REST.

Comment: Actually, whether it's 50ms or 600ms, it's all in a reasonable time range. The response time is related with your internet speed, load speed, server space or other factors. These factors would be different even you run the same page the next time. And your http status is 200 OK, so I suppose that is not a bug.

Comment: In this official  [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-azure-web-apps), you could also see the same page has different response time. This is normal.

Comment: Thanks and I will check the article.

Comment: Per my check it seems not a restart but a new instance created for simultaneous incoming REST request.
Say if 2 REST requests come to the app to handle the both efficiently the app create another application to handle the 2 requests simultaneously.
For azure api app is the mentioned scenario as the expected?

Comment: For azure api app there seems be thread pool to handle simultaneous multiple REST requests? 
If yes then for each thread the constructor for "class WebApiApplication" should be called?

Comment: It seems to be a new question. I'm not very familiar to this. If your original issue is solved, you could mark it as answer to close this thread.To avoid too long conversations, I suggest you could post a new thread to ask for the simultaneous handle in azure rest api. Thanks!

Comment: Sure and I will close this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe long time response - not an cause, It is an effect?
After restart - first several request are too long.

Anyway You should find the reason of restart, just research azure web app info:
- health tab
- azure service logs (by default they are in logs folder of you web app (open yourWebSite.scm.azure-websites.com)), you can find them in azure web apps tabs too.
- on scm you can find much more helpfull info about web app (not only logs, but also diagnostic dump, events and others)
- events tab.

Comment: Thanks for comments. If I did not trigger REST request to the app, there will no restart. Only when I trigger REST request to the app the restart is observed occasionally. So I think the REST request caused the restart.
Anyway I will have a check per your suggestions.